# How do you restart unity? I have no menu bars

Tags: unity, vmware, restart

Yesterday after running my ubuntu HDD in VMware on win7 I found that I had somehow lost unity. Even after actually booting into Ubuntu, unity was GONE. Every answer on the web couldn't bring it back. Finally, I reformatted and reinstalled ubuntu.

Now, while trying to figure out how in god's name to run a .run file, I ended up punching in a command that somehow disabled unity. I cannot get it back. "unity --reset" doesn't work. (ERROR: the reset option is now deprecated)

I can log out and log in as a guest, and bam, unity is there. But if I log into my account it is just a desktop wallpaper and nothing more.

I'm about to give up on converting to linux, and I'm a computer savvy person. I thought I could handle this, but this is just ridiculous. I've spent HOURS researching ways to restart unity. I can't just reformat every time Unity doesn't restart.

In summation: I cannot restart Unity. Someone...please...I'm begging you help me. I don't want to go back to windows.